# Billdesk payment integrations in php

Tags: php, payment

I am trying to find ways to integrate bill desk payment in php , but i am not able to find
any code snippet in php , However there are no any clues for sandbox environment in billdesk

Can any one please give me right steps to integrate billdesk with php?

Answer (score 1):

First Create Order api which will return you a authToken and bOrderid.
Make Sure Your Ip is not Black listed on BillDesk side...

```
function orderCreate()
{
         $headers = ["alg" => "HS256", "clientid" => 'YOUR CLIENT ID'];

        $payload = [
          "mercid" => 'YOUR MERCHANT ID',
          "orderid" => 'RANDOM STRING' // must be unique for every request
          "amount" => "300.00",
          "order_date" => '2023-03-24T10:59:15+05:30',
          "currency" => "356", // for INR
          "ru" => 'Return Url',
          "additional_info" => [
            "additional_info1" => 'q34324',
            "additional_info2" => 'dsaasaasd',
          ],
          "itemcode" => "DIRECT",
          "device" => [
            "init_channel" => "internet",
            "ip" => 'YOUR IP ADDRESS',
            //"mac" => '',  //not mandatory 
            //"imei" => '14134234343242', //not mandatory
            "accept_header" => "text/html", 
            "user_agent"=> "Windows 10",
           // "fingerprintid" => '' //not mandatory
          ]
        ];
        

        $this->load->library('jwt');
        $curl_payload = $this->jwt->encode($payload, 'YOUR SECRET KEY', "HS256", null ,$headers); // you should use Firebase/JWT library to encrypt the response

        $ch = curl_init( 'https://pguat.billdesk.io/payments/ve1_2/orders/create' );

        $ch_headers = array(
            "Content-Type: application/jose",
            "accept: application/jose",
            "BD-Traceid: RANDOM STRING",
            "BD-Timestamp: 20200817132207"
        );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ch_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_payload);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                            
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        
        curl_close($ch);
        

        /*****************************************/
                 // Billdesk Response
        /*****************************************/
        
        $launch_billdesk = false;
        try { 
            $result_decoded = $this->jwt->decode($result, 'Cjlj6qiBlQ7qdnglXvlJCKY1t3rNk7x4', array('HS256'));

            $result_array = (array) $result_decoded;

            if ($result_decoded->status == 'ACTIVE') {
                echo $result_array;
            } else { // Response error
                echo "Response error";
            }
                            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
          echo $e;
        }
  
    }
```

After getting OauthToken and bOrderId... launch bill desk sdk

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="module" src="https://uat.billdesk.com/jssdk/v1/dist/billdesksdk/billdesksdk.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule="" src="https://uat.billdesk.com/jssdk/v1/dist/billdesksdk.js"></script>
    <link href="https://uat.billdesk.com/jssdk/v1/dist/billdesksdk/billdesksdk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>

        var flow_config = {
            merchantId: "YOUR MERCHANT ID",
            bdOrderId: "OADY19XTURZ7NE", // get from orderCreate response
            authToken: "OToken 90FA4D84784AD18EEB9833BBD0CA27AFC045BD17FD625B4C43C85B8C0FCEB941573F37C0D8D6870257493C1AB70C702BEC3D8266786C3A0E8DB9FE10882F0A270C5D32F07CADFC5E86920333673BA4B48F7E0FE7867694F0D237F154211B8E29D789DBD4A4D8202BB0E5BC46134EBF963ED82724B561DB305946A246968C38524DD26BB660B63BCDE9E879583616B2A767B5C5C867272FFA16976B.4145535F55415431", // get from orderCreate response
            childWindow: false,
            returnUrl: "Return URL",
            crossButtonHandling: 'Y',
            retryCount: 0
        };
        var responseHandler = function (txn) {
            if (txn.response) {
                alert("callback received status:: ", txn.status);
                alert("callback received response:: ", txn.response);
            }
        };

        var config = {
            flowConfig: flow_config,
            flowType: "payments"
        };
        window.onload = function () {
            window.loadBillDeskSdk(config);
        };

    </script>
    
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is correct answer. this should be marked as accepted so it will help other developers too

Answer (score 0):

The bank itself would be expected to provide such tutorials.

If you can't find any on their site, then it's unlikely that you'll find them elsewhere unless it's a bank that's already very widely used for online transaction processing. Call them and ask them what help they can provide. Banks I've worked with have always been very happy to help.

Rather than just integrating into your website, it can be helpful to use an existing, popular shopping cart system e.g. [Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/), which will have a lot of the code you need already in place and will have examples of where similar plugins has been done with other banks, e.g. [here.](http://www.ubercart.org/project/uc_alpha_deltapay)